# How to change whole app's theme when used within Class, Tkinter, ttkThemes, ThemedTk Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Summary:
I searched the internet about additional themes for tkinter. I found ttkthemes - ThemedTk option. However, my app is created within class. The difference between the example shown in the module website, the themedtk example is applied with root method. Here is the code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk,THEMES
class App(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.style = ThemedTk
    self.title(dil_sec[0])
    self.geometry("800x600")
    self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
    self.my_notebook.pack(pady=15)
    self.my_menu = Menu(self)
    self.config(menu=self.my_menu)
    rec = None
    id_num = None
    self.first_lane = Menu(self.my_menu)
    self.my_menu.add_cascade(label=dil_sec[6], menu=self.first_lane)
    self.first_lane.add_command(label=dil_sec[2], command=self.customer_list)
    self.first_lane.add_command(label=dil_sec[1], command=lambda: self.customer_add(rec, id_num))
    self.second_lane = Menu(self.my_menu)
    self.my_menu.add_cascade(label=dil_sec[3], menu=self.second_lane)
    self.third_lane = Menu(self.my_menu)
    self.my_menu.add_cascade(label= dil_sec[65], menu=self.third_lane)
    self.third_lane.add_command(label=THEMES[0],command=lambda: self.stil_changer(still=THEMES[0]))
    self.third_lane.add_command(label=THEMES[1],command=lambda: self.stil_changer(still=THEMES[1]))

def stil_changer(self,still):
    print(still)
    self.style.set_theme(self,theme_name=still)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = App()
   app.mainloop()
```

When I run the application and the click the style and choose a style. I receive this error:

AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute '_toplevel'

It took so much time of me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `()` in line

```
self.style = ThemedTk()
```

and later you have to remove `self` in

```
self.style.set_theme(theme_name=still)
```

and now it runs without error but still it doesn't change theme.

Maybe it needs to use widgets from `ttk`.

---

**EDIT:**

You have to use `ThemedTk` in place of `tk.Tk`. And use directly `self.set_theme()`

And of course you need some widgets from `ttk`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class App(ThemedTk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.geometry("800x600")
        
        self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.my_notebook.pack(pady=15, fill='both', expand=True)
        
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.my_notebook)
        self.my_notebook.add(self.frame, text='Buttons')
        for number in range(10):
            b = ttk.Button(self.frame, text=str(number))
            b.pack()
        
        self.my_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.my_menu)
        
        self.first_lane = tk.Menu(self.my_menu)
        self.first_lane.add_command(label='a')
        self.first_lane.add_command(label='b')
        self.my_menu.add_cascade(label='Menu1', menu=self.first_lane)
        
        self.second_lane = tk.Menu(self.my_menu)
        self.my_menu.add_cascade(label='Menu2', menu=self.second_lane)
        
        self.third_lane = tk.Menu(self.my_menu)
        self.my_menu.add_cascade(label='Style', menu=self.third_lane)
        
        for item in sorted(self.get_themes()):
            self.third_lane.add_command(label=item, command=lambda name=item: self.changer_theme(name))
    
    def changer_theme(self, name):
        print('theme:', name)
        self.set_theme(name)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = App()
   app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Or you can use `Tk` with `ThemedStyle` (instead of `ThemedTk`)
and then you can set `self.style = ThemedStyle()`
but you have to use `self.style.theme_use(name)` instead of `self.set_theme(name)`

And it needs `self.style.get_themes()` instead of `self.get_themes()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.geometry("800x600")
        
        self.style = ThemedStyle()   # with Tk and ThemedStyle
        
        self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.my_notebook.pack(pady=15, fill='both', expand=True)
        
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.my_notebook)
        self.my_notebook.add(self.frame, text='Buttons')
        for number in range(10):
            b = ttk.Button(self.frame, text=str(number))
            b.pack()
        
        self.my_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.my_menu)
        
        self.first_lane = tk.Menu(self.my_menu)
        self.first_lane.add_command(label='a')
        self.first_lane.add_command(label='b')
        self.my_menu.add_cascade(label='Menu1', menu=self.first_lane)
        
        self.second_lane = tk.Menu(self.my_menu)
        self.my_menu.add_cascade(label='Menu2', menu=self.second_lane)
        
        self.third_lane = tk.Menu(self.my_menu)
        self.my_menu.add_cascade(label='Style', menu=self.third_lane)
        
        #for item in sorted(self.get_themes()):       # with ThemedTk
        for item in sorted(self.style.get_themes()): # with Tk and ThemedStyle
            self.third_lane.add_command(label=item, command=lambda name=item: self.changer_theme(name))
    
    def changer_theme(self, name):
        print('theme:', name)
        #self.set_theme(name)        # with ThemedTk
        self.style.theme_use(name)   # with Tk and ThemedStyle
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = App()
   app.mainloop()
```

I found screenshots for all themes: [List of ttk Themes](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes)

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I have only working example with `ttk.Buttons`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkthemes

root = tk.Tk()

root.style = ttkthemes.ThemedStyle()
    
for i, name in enumerate(sorted(root.style.theme_names())):
    b = ttk.Button(root, text=name, command=lambda name=name:root.style.theme_use(name))
    b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Default:

[image]

Blue:

[image]

Kroc:

[image]

Radiance or Ubuntu:

[image]

Winxpblue:

[image]

---

Source keep on GitHub: [furas / python-examples / tkinter / themes-change-ttkthemes / buttons](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/themes-change-ttkthemes/buttons)

Comment: Thank you very much @furas. Just before you answer it I figured out by altering below __main__. I moved the root there and it worked but while trying themes I noticed that the width and height of the widgets changed. I will try your answer as well. This is the first proper solution I received among my queries.