# How to make custom scrollbar in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I wanted to create a custom scrollbar without arrows in `tkinter`,  `Python 3.7`, `Windows 7`.

Below is some example:

[image]

Comment: I mean that I wanted a scrollbar without arrow and of above design

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: `tkinter` has standard module `tkinter.ttk` with widgets which can use themes - and maybe one of themes has scrollbars like this. `tkinter` can also use external modules which can add themes - like [ttkthemes](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes.html)

Comment: other idea: you can use `tkinter.Canvas` to create own scrollbar from scratch

Comment: [How to change whole app's theme when used within Class, Tkinter, ttkThemes, ThemedTk Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726458/how-to-change-whole-apps-theme-when-used-within-class-tkinter-ttkthemes-them)

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter` has standard module `tkinter.ttk` with widgets which can use `themes` and maybe one of themes has scrollbars like this.

`tkinter` can also use external modules which can add themes - like [ttkthemes](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes.html)

---

Minimal working example

It displays buttons with all themes and with scrollbar (on the right) and you can see how scrollbar looks in other themes.

Screenshots from Linux Mint 21. I don't know if Windows has the same themes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

def changer_theme(name):
    print('theme:', name)
    #root.set_theme(name)        # with ThemedTk
    style.theme_use(name)   # with Tk and ThemedStyle

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

style = ThemedStyle()   # with Tk and ThemedStyle
        
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side='left')

for item in sorted(style.get_themes()): # with Tk and ThemedStyle
    b = ttk.Button(frame, text=item, command=lambda name=item: changer_theme(name))
    b.pack(fill='x')
    
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

root.mainloop()
```

---

Old question with code using classes:

[How to change whole app's theme when used within Class, Tkinter, ttkThemes, ThemedTk Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726458/how-to-change-whole-apps-theme-when-used-within-class-tkinter-ttkthemes-them)

Documentation for `tcl/tk`: [List of ttk Themes](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes). It shows other widgets.

---

Adapta:

[image]

Breeze:

[image]

Scidblue / Scidgreen / etc.

[image]

Yaru:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you soo much for helping me but please tell can I get same design like this in windows because I want this rounded edges design not colou

Comment: theme `Adapta` has rounded edges. And if you need modifications then you may have to learn how to use `Style` in `tkinter`. But it can be complex and I don't know tutorial for this.

Comment: some information about `styling`: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html

Comment: Thanks you I searching this for a long time please tell one more thing can I create second scrollbar that is in image that I posted above the sharp edges scrollbar without arrows

Comment: I never tried this but you may try to modify theme using `style`. Link  https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html . You may try to find source code for `themes` and check how it define elements and modify it.